# size() function in pyautogui module

Tags: python, pyautogui

I need to get the size of the screen for a project I am working on. A complication here is when a monitor is connected to the CPU, that function returns the size of the monitor. But if I connect to a projector instead, say, SVGA quality of dimension 320*240 resolution, will that function return me the corresponding tuple, or would it throw me an error?

And what is the outcome when we don't have a monitor connected at all? Can somebody try and post back? P.S.: I don't have a desktop. We will be installing it on RPI eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but i will try to help you... to get the screen size using pyautogui, use this function: `pyautogui.size()`

Pyautogui use pixels as reference. You can try to set your screen definition or use coordenates to find images: `pyautogui.click(x=100, y= 200)` or `pyautogui.doubleClick(x=100, y=200)`.

X and Y are coordenates!

[More info here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks)